# How to change the value of a field mongodb nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This is the Schema of the model:

```
{
  season: 1,
  finished: 0,
  Games: [{
    Game: [
        {
            game: 1,
            Players: [
              {
                Id: 0,
                name: "Peter",
                points: 3
              },
              {
                Id: 1,
                name: "Yusuf",
                points: 2
              }
            ]
         },
         {
            game: 2,
            Players: [
              {
                Id: 0,
                name: "Peter",
                points: 2
              },
              {
                Id: 1,
                name: "Yusuf",
                points: 3
              }
            ]
         }
     ]
  }]
}
```

I tried the query at the bottom but it's not working as I want. I want to change only the selected Game's `game` field but it changes all `game` fields of all `Games` to the same value in the same season.

```
Seasons.update(
{season:1, "Games.Game.game":2},
{$set: {
    Games: {
        Game: {
            game: 5
        }
    }
 }},
 (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log(data)
    }
  }
)
```

The question is "How to select and update a value of children array of a record?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use arrayFilters [`$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/), identifies the array elements that match the arrayFilters conditions for an update operation,

- [`$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/), the positional operator indicates that the update operator should modify all elements in the specified array field.
- `$[g]` refers to arrayFilters condition

```
await Seasons.update(
  {
    season: 1,
    "Games.Game.game": 2
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "Games.$[].Game.$[g].game": 5
    }
  },
  { 
    arrayFilters: [
      { "g.game": 2 }
    ] 
  },
  (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log(data)
    }
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JG8KJT-LJu0)

Comment: It works, thank you mate. But I couln't understand the case totally. Can you give me a source on this topic?

Comment: i have attached link in answer for $[] and $[<identifier>], you can just click on that.